# Backing up server data (20+ TB) into a 10 TB external disk in a compressed format preserving permissions, symlinks, hierarchies etc

Tags: ubuntu, server, backup, admin

How do I backup data from a Ubuntu server into an external hard disk by (a) retaining the permissions, and symlinks of the folders (b) having the backup in a compressed format?

I have 20+ TB data in my server and I have a hard disk with 10 TB space. I would like to backup the data on the server into the external disk in a compressed format with the permissions, hierarchy and symlinks retained. I understand that `gzip --rsyncable` wouldn't save any space while `rsync` can't be used to compress the data. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean incremental or repeated backups which replace the previous backup each time ? Or just a one-off backup ?

Comment: @patraulea, incremental backups would be ideal but wouldn't mind repeated backups since the frequency of backups is not going to be very high.